# Microsoft Access Pivot table to SQL Server Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, pivot

I am new to SQL Server and need to convert the following MS Access Pivot query to SQL Pivot Query.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
TRANSFORM First(msdgen_pmcat_document_extract_mats.document_text) AS FirstOfdocument_text
SELECT msdgen_pmcat_document_extract_mats.material_id, msdgen_pmcat_document_extract_mats.documentobject_name, msdgen_pmcat_document_extract_mats.regulatory_code, msdgen_pmcat_document_extract_mats.alternate_name
FROM msdgen_pmcat_document_extract_mats
GROUP BY msdgen_pmcat_document_extract_mats.material_id, msdgen_pmcat_document_extract_mats.documentobject_name, msdgen_pmcat_document_extract_mats.regulatory_code, msdgen_pmcat_document_extract_mats.alternate_name
PIVOT msdgen_pmcat_document_extract_mats.data_type_code;
```

Comment: What did you try?   What error are you getting?   You need to show how you attempted to research and solve this so that we can help you.

Comment: Part of your problem is going to be the MS Access function `FIRST()` SQL Server doesn't have an equivalent function.  What does your table and its data look like in `msdgen_pmcat_document_extract_mats` and how do you want the final result to appear?

Answer (score -2):

A simple search for "MS SQL PIVOT" would give you all the help you need:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177410(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: Your link relates to Microsoft SQL Server, not for MS Access!